# Linq syntax for a nested join query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

So the premise is I have a table called recipes, each recipe has ingredients. And I want to build a shopping list.

Currently what I am doing is :-

```
List<ingredient> UsedIngredients = new List<ingredient>();

foreach (var item in this.Recipes)
{
    foreach (var ingredient in item.ingredients)
    {
        if (!UsedIngredients .Contains(ingredient))
        {
            UsedIngredients .Add(ingredient);
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can simplify it down to

```
List<ingredient> UsedIngredients = new List<ingredient>();

foreach (var item in this.Recipes)
{
    foreach (var ingredient in item.ingredients.Where(ingredient => !UsedIngredients .Contains(ingredient)))
    {
        UsedIngredients.Add(ingredient);
    }
}
```

Simple enough, but I'm thinking there must be a short hand method to do this in linq, i.e get a list of ALL ingredients used for ALL selected recipes.

Also please note that

`Recipes` is a List of type `recipe`
Type `recipe` has a property ingredients which is a join to a ingredients table using a intermediately many-to-many join table (factored away by EF to just be `.ingedients`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're trying to get a collection of unique ingredients from the recipes.

```
var usedIngredients =
    (from recipe in this.Recipes
    from ingredient in recipe.ingredients
    select ingredient).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't even aware you could have two from commands in the one linq query - this makes a few other things much easier as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void Test()
     {
         List<Recipes> recipes = new List<Recipes>();
         List<Ingredient> UsedIngredients = new List<Ingredient>();
         UsedIngredients = (from a in recipes where UsedIngredients.Contains(a.ingredient) select a.ingredient).ToList();
     }
```

Please try this